# Error in reading awsconfiguration.json for GoogleSignIn

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services

when I tried to start using AWS, I got this error.
I followed the exact same way as this link. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html#connect-to-your-backend

How can I fix this?

[This is the error what I got.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oexol.png)

Answer (score 4):

This error getting logged in the console can be ignored. This was a bug in 2.6.7 version. It has been fixed in one of the latest releases. Please upgrade to 2.6.15 or latest and you will not see this exception anymore.